# How can I reset a single state prop to its initial values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that contains the following constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    stage: TIMER_PREPARED,
    remaining: this.props.seconds,
    flashNotification: {
      message: null,
      shown: false,
      code: null,
    }
  };
}
```

At a certain point during the app lifecycle I need to reset the flashNotification props to their initial state.

Is there a way to do that without resetting the rest of the props?
Meaning, without using:

```
this.setState({flashNotification: {
      message: null,
      shown: false,
      code: null,
    }})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I undertand the question. What would be the desired outcome?

Comment: Resetting the value of flashNotification without having to pass all the values for its child properties

Comment: Ori Drori's answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks @jsalonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize flashNotification using a factory function:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);   

    this.state = {
      stage: TIMER_PREPARED,
      remaining: this.props.seconds,
      flashNotification: this.createFlashNotification()
    };  
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({ flashNotification: this.createFlashNotification() });
  }

  createFlashNotification() {
    return {
      message: null,
      shown: false,
      code: null
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: @yahyazini - this is better and simpler answer. You should go with this.

Answer (score 1):

To reset `flashNotification` to a base value. You can store the object on `this`, and clone it whenever you want to reset:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.flashNotification = Object.freeze({ // Object.freeze is used to prevent changes to the base object
      message: null,
      shown: false,
      code: null,
    });

    this.state = {
      stage: TIMER_PREPARED,
      remaining: this.props.seconds,
      flashNotification: Object.assign({}, this.flashNotification) // cloning the object
    };

    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({ flashNotification: Object.assign({}, this.flashNotification })// cloning the object
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm currently using, is there a way to reset flashNotification without knowing passing values to its props.

Comment: I feel like this is a really great solution. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is keep a copy of the initial State in a class object and then reset it whenever necessary like

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.baseFlashNotification = {
      message: null,
      shown: false,
      code: null,
    }

  this.state = {
    stage: TIMER_PREPARED,
    remaining: this.props.seconds,
    flashNotification: Object.assign({}, this.baseFlashNotification)
  };
}
```

and reset as

```
  this.setState({flashNotification: this.baseFlashNotification})
```